# Which is better way to filter in cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a doubt about the optimization of cypher query while filtering.
There is a relation between Entity and Address Node. Here is two query -

```
match(a:Address)<-[r]-(e:Entity) where a.addressLocation=~".*(?i)ABC XYZ.*" return r

match(e:Entity)-[r]->(a:Address) where a.addressLocation=~".*(?i)ABC XYZ.*" return r
```

Which is better among these above two query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use command

```
profile match(a:Address)<-[r]-(e:Entity) where a.addressLocation=~".*(?i)ABC XYZ.*" return r
profile match(e:Entity)-[r]->(a:Address) where a.addressLocation=~".*(?i)ABC XYZ.*" return r
```

To see if there is any distinction in your version of neo in this two queries. 
Also I suggest that if you know that there is small number of Addresses with creteria `a.addressLocation=~".*(?i)ABC XYZ.*"`
Try to use query like

```
 match(a:Address) where a.addressLocation=~".*(?i)ABC XYZ.*" 
 with a Match (a)<-[r]-(e:Entity) return r
```

To learn more about profiling look here http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/execution-plans.html